# How to block acces for all methods to Admin Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-form-helper

I need to block access to other methods in Admin controller if admin is not logged in.For example if I write base_url/administration/show/index I can access without login in system
Pleez help,Thx

Login Controller:

```
class Login extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index(){
        // Load our view to be displayed
        // to the user
        $this->load->view('admin/authentification_view');
    }

    public function process()
    {
        // Load the model
        $this->load->model('login_model');
        // Validate the user can login
        $result = $this->login_model->validate();
        // Now we verify the result
        if(! $result){
            // If user did not validate, then show them login page again
            $this->index();
        }else{
            // If user did validate, 
            // Send them to members area
            redirect('administration/show/index');
        }        
    }

}
```

Login Model

```
class Login_model extends CI_Model{
   function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
   }

   public function validate()
   {
        $login = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('login'));
        $password = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('password'));
        $this->db->where('login', $login);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);
        $query = $this->db->get('admin_details');
        if($query->num_rows == 1)
        {
            // Creare date sesiuni
            $row = $query->row();
            $data = array(
                'id' => $row->id,
                'login' => $row->login,
                'password' => $row->password,
                'validated' => true
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Administration Controller

```
class Administration extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('administration_page_model');
        $this->load->model('crud');
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }  

    public function logout()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('login');
    }

    public function show($admin_page)
    {  

            $data = array();
            $data["news"] = $this->administration_model->allNews();
            switch($admin_page)
            {
                case 'index':
                    $name = 'admin/index';
                    $this->display_lib->admin_page($data,$name);
                    break;
                case 'add_news':
                    $name = 'admin/addnews';
                    $this->display_lib->admin_page($data,$name);
                    break;
                case 'all':
                    $name = 'admin/all';
                    $this->display_lib->admin_page($data,$name);
                    break;

            }
    }
}
```

Comment: All external methods check whether user logged in before doing other actions. Rename the internal methods to have underscore in the start.

Comment: How to verify this? I have tried but no resultats

Comment: I used to have a helper function isLoggedIn() and use it the start of each function. If Not logged display message and return;

Comment: why not you put some code in controller __construct, if ($this->login_model->validate() == FALSE) {
redirect('redirect-path');
}

Comment: in your login_model validate() you can set check for if ($this->session->userdata('validated') == TRUE)
return True; else FALSE;

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a helper function check_login() to cjeck if user is logged in and the call this helper in your constructor for every class where you need to check login .

```
public function check_login(){
    $ci = & get_instance();
   if(!isset($ci->session->userdata['validated']))
   {
     //do what u want if user is not loogged in
     //for example redirect('home page url');
   }

}
```

Now in every constructor just add this line

```
check_login();
```

to learn more about helper functions see

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html

Comment: I created this helper but I received a error:Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context
<?php
if (! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access');

 function check_login()
 {
      if(isset($this->session->userdata('validated')))
      {
        return true;
      }
       else
       {
        return false;
       }
 }

?>

Comment: where did u write this function ??

Comment: U have to write this function in a helper file .

Comment: first create a file named my_helper.php in application/helpers folder
then in your application/config/autoload.php find this line 
`$config['helper']` and make it `$config['helper'] = array('my_helper');`

Comment: Yes I created a file auth_helper.php in folder helpers

Comment: u need to load the helper in autoload.php  file use this  `$config['helper'] = array('auth_helper');`

Comment: Men I load the helper but when execute I got this error:Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context

Comment: change code to this `public function check_login(){
   if(!isset($this->session->userdata('validated')))
     //redirect to page where u want him him instead of current page
}`

Comment: when I login I got another error:Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in auth_helper

Comment: I need to add in constructor only check_login();?

Comment: yes and in that function just redirect him to page where u want him if he is not logged in ..

Comment: u were reciving error first time because $this->session->userdata() is a function and isset() is used to check variables....second time u recived error because u cant use $this outside a class i.e in a helper function

Comment: I get no error login go but when I write in browser base_url/administration/show/index and I'am not log it goes

Comment: if I write base_url/administration/show/index I can access without login in system..This helper didn't solved my problem

Comment: just add `$this ->session->all_userdata();` to check your userdata at time of login ..if your session is being set or not

Comment: where I must add this?

Comment: anywhere where u want to check ur session variables ..just write 

`echo '<pre>';print_r($this->session->all_userdata());exit;`

Comment: Array
(
    [session_id] => ab89f61a5bc367f8f2207ce061c98e21
    [ip_address] => 127.0.0.1
    [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0
    [last_activity] => 1393419425
    [user_data] => 
)
maybe the problem is here because in my config:
$config['sess_cookie_name']  = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_table_name']  = 'ci_sessions';

But my table in database is admin_details

Comment: no thats not the problem but it is sure that ur session is not being set

Answer (score 0):

The easiest seperation would be to define the following classes in application/core:

Base_Controller extends CI_Controller
- some basic stuff, setting vars etc

Admin_Controller extends Base_Controller
- integrate your logic/library that determines a user as an admin
- for example: If(!isAdmin) -> redirect to login

Auth_Controller extends Base_Controller
- for example: If(!isLoggedIn) -> redirect to login

Front_Controller extends Base_Controller
- no need for auth or admin, then use this one

Comment: This idea with helper is very good but I don't understand why i received this error

Comment: Maybe your authentication process is a bit buggy. I would recommend the above Admin_Controller. And use it for every area that should be proteced and only accessible for admin.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put in the constructor of any admin controller :

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    if(!$this->session->userdata('validated')) redirect('login');
}
```

You can also check out Ion_Auth plugin (it manages authentifications, accounts, etc). You will just need to call :

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    if(!$this->ion_auth->logged_in()) redirect('login');
}
```